# Python convert seconds to datetime date and time

Tags: python, datetime

How do I convert an int like `1485714600` such that my result ends up being `Monday, January 30, 2017 12:00:00 AM`?

I've tried using `datetime.datetime` but it gives me results like '5 days, 13:23:07'

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
'Sunday, January 29, 2017 08:30:00'
```

Comment: Indeed! However, in the end I am trying to conduct this operation on a list of seconds, all of which I am trying to convert to the above datetime format. The loop I run keeps giving me an index out of bounds error. Any thoughts?                                                                                                    `for j in ts_date:
ts_date[j] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_date[j]).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")`

Comment: @tushariyer need to see your code.

Comment: if you are iterating over a list, and trying to modify the value based on the positional key, you should be using the built-in `enumerate` function: `for j, val in enumerate(ts_date):` ..

Answer (score 17):

What you describe here is a *(Unix) timestamp* (the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970). You can use:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600)
```

This will generate:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600)
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 29, 19, 30)
```

You can get the *name* of the day by using `.strftime('%A')`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600).strftime('%A')
'Sunday'
```

Or you can call `weekday()` to obtain an integers between `0` and `6` (both inclusive) that maps thus from monday to sunday:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600).weekday()
6
```

Comment: Thank you! As a secondary question, would you know how I could use that to return just the day of the week (Monday-sunday)? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600).weekday()