# How to convert timedelta.total_seconds() float into datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

I have converted a datetime with microseconds into a timedelta.total_seconds() object which is a float.

How can I convert this float back into datetime, preferably with `%H:%M:%S.%f` format?

Comment: do you have a reference date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert seconds to datetime date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140034/python-convert-seconds-to-datetime-date-and-time)