# how to ignore zero values in python

Tags: python

time =int(input())

day = time // (24 * 3600)

time = time % (24 * 3600)

hour = time // 3600

time %= 3600

minutes = time // 60

time %= 60

seconds = time

if day > 0:

```
print((str(int(day))+(" Days"))+(" ")+(str(int(hour))+(" Hours"))+(" ")+(str(int(minutes)) + (" Minutes"))+(" ")+ (str(int(seconds)) + (" Seconds")))
```

elif hour > 0:

```
print((str(int(hour)) + " Hours") +(" ") + (str(int(minutes)) + " Minutes") + (" ")+ (str(int(seconds)) + " Seconds"))
```

elif minutes > 0:

```
print((str(int(minutes)) + " Minutes") + (" ")+ (str(int(seconds)) + " Seconds"))
```

else:

```
print(str(int(seconds)) + " Seconds")
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? You should add more information.

Comment: you might want to consider using `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.time` for those types of things. It has very convinient built in methods to handle your problem

Comment: this might also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140034/python-convert-seconds-to-datetime-date-and-time

Answer (score 0):

you can simple ignore null values by an if condition like:

```
if (data != np.nan)
```

or for zero values:

```
if (data != 0)
```

or for data greater than and not equal to 0:

```
if (data != 0) and (data > 0)
```

and same can be done with elif.
you can take "data" variable as any list or value/number.

Comment: I couldn't understad.could you please expain breefly.

Comment: like you asked how to ignore zero values using if, elif statements in python:  you can do this ```if (day != 0) and (day > 0)```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def timeFormat():
  sec = timedelta(seconds=int(input('Enter seconds')))
  d = datetime(1,1,1) + sec
  # insert some logic here to get rid of values == 0
  print('{} days, {} hours, {} minutes, {} seconds'.format(d.day-1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second))
```